# What was the name of this webservice where you can define simple chains of if/then tasks?

Tags: web-services

It had some letters in its name, a fairly recent new webservice which I found uninteresting when I first found it but kept remembering and wanted to give it a spin now. But I can't remeber the name.

It is like an uptime tester with added functionality, you could poll websites, emailboxes, webservices, etc. and then define a hook that is being executed when a certain condition is met, making automated private mashups for you.

Certainly, as with everything coming from the Valley, I only hit this one service back then, while a number of startups actually are exploring this concept. So links welcome...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[IFTTT.com](http://ifttt.com)

IfThisThenThat allows you to create personal recipes which allow you to monitor webpages and such for changes and perform an action based on the change.

From Wikipedia: IFTTT is a service that enables customers to connect channels (i.e. Facebook, Evernote, Weather, Dropbox, etc.) with personally created or publicly shared profiles known as "recipes".

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for IF This Then That: [ifttt.com](https://ifttt.com/)